# Parallel ForEach() loop keeps on repeating on just 1 item. Why?

Tags: c#, process, parallel-processing

I got a listbox of items and a cmd process which I wanna do for each item in the listbox.
So my code is:

```
    public void Hs(ListBox list) 
        {
         IEnumerable<String> data = new List<String>(list.Items.Cast<String>());

         Parallel.ForEach(data, (item) =>
                {
                    listBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                     {
                        //Show which file in listbox is processing  
                        listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(item));  
                     }));

                 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                 ......
                });
        }
```

However, even if the list has just 1 item, it keeps on repeat processing again, again and again.

Thank you so much !

Comment: I suppose you are not checking that invokation is required in first place.

Comment: thanks you, i'm testing it right now, but i believe that the invokation in't the main cause of the repeat problem. I think it is because of the parallel foreach:(

Comment: I think this is because of `ListBox` when you are manipulating shared object in `Parallel` you should `lock` it.

Comment: i use "IEnumerable<String> data" to represent the listbox, so that should i lock the "data" ?

Comment: I meant it it is better to lock shared resource in `Parallel` if you are manipulating it, so it may because of shared Items or something else.

Comment: I would suggest that you don't use `Parallel.For`. Use a normal for-loop, start the process, listen to `Process.Exited` and then start the next process. That way you can easily start/run multiple processes without the TPL, locking and invoking...